# Why did the OP's user number change?

Tags: discussion

This is a bit weird. An unregistered user asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282993/installing-ubuntu-on-a-powerbook-g4-667-unable-to-boot) here. Then instead of editing the question or adding comments, he started posting additional informations as answers. When I first noticed this I left a message telling him to edit the question. Then I noticed that the user number changed for him. I.E. he was no longer responding as the OP. How do we deal with a situation like that? Why did it happen?

In this situation, can the OP access the unregistered account to manage the question at this point? I'm at an absolute loss!

Comment: btw, I've noticed similar behavior from unregistered users with the *same name* [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283338/ubuntu-restart-to-continue) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283032/lower-version-of-ubuntu). I suppose that it's possible that multiple people name Chris just happened to pick the same day to use askUbuntu for the first time and all have had either their cookies disabled or felt like jumping browser to browser...

Comment: and [another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/283775/i-need-to-put-ubuntu-on-a-dead-apple-desktop-using-an-apple-laptop-how-do-i-d) appears...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when people use unregistered accounts. The only way to "access" an unregistered account is to use the browser you registered it on. So if you remove that cookie or use another browser/computer you'll have to create another unregistered account. If the user creates an account either with Stack Exchange or via OpenID login and the email address for that new account is the same as the unregistered accounts the system should automatically merge them and the user can then manage the question.

Comment: Now, about [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282993/installing-ubuntu-on-a-powerbook-g4-667-unable-to-boot), the OP can no longer post anything on the page. I'm assuming that the OP has either cookies disabled or deletes them regularly and does not have any stack exchange accounts. If he were to register, he would start out with 1 rep. As his question is now protected, he can no longer add more information or comment on the problem. Even if his question was valid, should it not now be deleted?

Comment: @Nil No, not yet. The devs can merge all the unregistered accounts with the registered one and he'll get access to his question back. The only problem is, *he* has to ask them to do it.

Comment: Nil he can still merge his accounts, and his reputation will be merged with it. If there was something they needed to do but couldn't they could flag the question for a moderator to help out.